# Bubble.io to Python encryption/decryption?

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pythonanywhere, bubble.io

I am building a POC for a project using Bubble.io to build the web app. I plan on using an API to send information from Bubble to a separate Flask app on PythonAnywhere, where a Python script will execute using some of the information passed by the API. Some of the information passed between Bubble and PythonAnywhere will be sensitive data.

I know there are ways to encrypt/decrypt in Bubble and there are also libraries in Python to encrypt/decrypt, but is there anyway to encrypt data in Bubble and decrypt in Python? I am pretty new to networking and APIs, so I wasn’t sure if this was possible.

I have tried researching encryption/decryption methods online, but can’t find any resources that describe encrypting in Bubble and decrypting in another system.

Comment: I don't know anything about Bubble and there are few details here but presumably HTTPS with POST method would be the easiest and most secure.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the lack of details, I wasn’t quite sure what to ask to convey my question. If using HTTPS and POST methods are secure enough, that is reassuring. I didn’t know if I had to encrypt the data sent via those methods as well.